# How do I avoid snoring when sharing a room in a hostel or lodge?

Tags: tips-and-tricks, hostels, sleeping, etiquette

I snore and I know it. This causes quite some discomfort when I need to share a room with others. I usually try to stay awake until everybody else seems to be sleeping. The pokes or the sudden shaking of the bed has caused quite some sleepless nights for me while traveling. 
Are there tricks to not disturb others with my snoring, and having a good nights rest?

To all the rich out there, I don't always have the funds to support 4 star single hotel rooms.

Comment: I found this link regarding snoring, not sure how well any of the tips will work? http://www.webmd.com/sleep-disorders/features/easy-snoring-remedies?page=2.                        Do you snore all the time or only under certain circumstances?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snoring can be a serious health issue and deteriorate your sleep quality, not only when others are disturbed by it. I would not consider this a travel issue for that reason.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about snoring, a medical condition - it's not really specifically relevant to travel.

Comment: @AndrewFerrier But it is totally relevant to traveling. At home you can either marry a fellow snorer or have snoring rooms. Snoring while traveling can cause much more annoyances then normal snoring at home.

Comment: Have you tried the nose-strips?  An adhesive strip that you put across the outside of your nose (parallell to your mouth, just below where glasses would rest), that's supposed to hold your nose more open.   Helps some kinds of snoring, I think. // (Big +1 on the tennis ball - that's clever!)

Comment: In case the answers given don't help, you may find yourself friends by generously distributing (unused!) [earplugs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earplug) in advance. Just make sure you test their comfort on yourself before expecting others to bear with that...

Comment: This is my first trip in ages where I didn't remember to grab a few pairs of earplugs from work before leaving. Now that I'm old though I've noticed I'm the offender more than the offended this time around! 0=

Comment: @hunter2 I certainly have! They work pretty well.

Comment: I had to stay in a twin room with my friend as we traveled Europe. He didn't just snore; it was more like a motorbike revving up every 4 seconds. After 3 days of this, wandering the halls of the various hotels because I couldn't sleep, he ended up wearing his half-full backpack every night - worked a charm and kept him on his back. If you're a really heavy snorer like him I've found the nose strips don't really work - the only solution that helped was him forcing himself to sleep on his back.

Answer (score 14):

**Sleep on your side.**

Sleeping on your stomach might also work. Avoid sleeping on your back at any rate.

Sometimes if I sleep on my stomach I get circulation problems to various areas of my body that I don't seem to get any other time. This never happens when sleeping on my side however.

**Also keep an eye on yourself.**

If you notice at any point that you've changed to your back then change to your side. If you've just moved from your side then try the other side for a while. If you wake yourself up with a loud snore take note of your position. You're probably on your back again so move to your side.

Try to take these measures especially if you've been drinking of have a head cold though perhaps these might induce snoring even if you avoid sleeping on your back - I'm not sure about that.

**Apologize in advance.**

If you know you're a bad snorer and not just an occasional snorer then advise the people sharing the room that they have your permission to kick you, wake you, throw pillows at you, etc should you begin snoring.

**Mitigation.**

There are some factors that will reduce the impact of snoring on other sleepers. In hot places such as the tropics having an air conditioner or one or more fans on through the night can help to mask the sound of snorers.
I also find snoring to be much more annoying in small dormitories with say four people than in large dormitories with ten or twenty people.
In my current trip in Southeast Asia I've been mostly in large dorms and always with aircon or fan on overnight and I either haven't noticed or have heard but not been kept awake by snorers in my room.

---

**It's a two-way street.**

Snoring is so common that anybody choosing shared sleeping quarters should always be aware that it's one of the possibilities they should include in their list of "cons". If it's such a huge problem that you know you can't sleep in a room with a snorer, then don't book such a room. If it's a hassle to share with a snorer but you decide it's worth it when taking into account the other benefits such as lower prices, then don't forget to take ear plugs. Opinions vary but I find them wonderfully helpful when used correctly.

Comment: A tennis ball sewed into the back of your t-shirt prevents rolling back.

Comment: @Andra: If any comment ever deserved the "pro tip" label, that was it! (=

Comment: +1 particularly to the last point. If people do have a big problem its not your fault. Its just the luck of the draw of who you end up sharing with. I have a much bigger problem with drunken party people who roll in noisily at 4AM. I even stayed in a hostel once where a couple of brothers had a loud noisy argument with each other at 4AM. Much harder to sleep through that than somebody snoring. :)

Comment: Yeah that, phone calls at full voice just outside the door at 4am, and of course sex in the other bed of your bunk! d-:

Comment: @hippietrail I never thoguht of the two-way street comment you made. I snore and I think its unfair when people say that people who snore should get single rooms or beds (which is more expensive)...It's not like we do it on purpose!

Comment: Some hostels try to manage snorers into the same dormitory - but it's not really easy.

Comment: @hippietrail - what was that "pro tip" comment from Andra? Seems it was deleted - is missing.

Comment: @PeterMasiar: I don't remember and I can't see deleted comments even though I can see deleted questions )-:

Answer (score 6):

[Believe it or not, those nasal strips with the tacky commercials *actually* work.](http://www.breatheright.com)

[image]

Spend the couple of bucks, stick one on your nose, and you'll breathe better and snore less. Essentially, what they do is physically pull your nostrils open just a little bit wider, allowing you to breathe through your nose more easily, which prevents most snoring.

Similarly, other means of reducing nasal congestion, whether it be a simple [over the counter decongestant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudoephedrine), or more natural tricks like a Neti Pot or saline rinse can also make a dramatic difference for many snorers.

Comment: I actually hadn't heard of those before. I wonder if they're available world-wide? Yes the decongestants truly help if the snoring is related to a cold, and so probably also if it's related to an allergy.

Comment: @hippietrail Yeah, they should be availiable worldwide. If not the name brand product I linked, than certainly a generic equivalent. (I was in a drug store this morning, and counted 6 brands of essentially the same product.)

Comment: Just a heads up on the decongestant - it's only over the counter in certain countries. In Japan at least pseudoephedrine (the active ingredient in certain sprays) is banned. Also, taking it too regularly can make the problem worse and stuff your nose up long-term (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhinitis_medicamentosa)

Comment: @codinghands other decongestants would work just fine as well. I just happened to link Pseudo.

Comment: True. The stuff I get over here is so weak though, so when my head gets bunged up it's ginger and hot water :(

Comment: Always have earplugs with you to share with your hostel mates.

Answer (score 4):

**[Sleep face down, on your stomach](http://edition.cnn.com/2011/HEALTH/04/19/healthiest.sleep.position/index.html)**.

As far as I know, snoring is more common when you sleep on your back. Sleeping face down, on your stomach, reduces snoring. It's pretty safe to do unless you have back pains, and make sure your pillow is a "low" one - not too fluffy and high because otherwise your neck will hurt a *lot*.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of options are mentioned here, but sometimes, there's just more to snoring. Snoring can be just a symptom for an underlying larger problem. Sleep Apnea is a really common reason behind snoring, especially if you wake up in the morning feeling groggy and tired. Long-term effects of sleep apnea are pretty bad.

To really address the underlying issue, and not the symptom, consider doing a Sleep Study. Some labs allow you to do a sleep study in our own home - they will send you a kit. If you are diagnosed with Sleep Apnea, definitely use a CPAP machine. You can even get a travel-sized mini CPAP machine wherever you travel. This machine will not only treat the underlying issue, but also completely eliminate your snoring.

Source: I used to snore loudly like a Jet engine all night. Every one - my family members, gfs, friends, room-mates, apartment mates, strangers, were all pissed with me for snoring. I finally did a sleep study and found I have mild Sleep Apnea. Started using CPAP machine and it's been super quiet. My snoring volume went from 70-80 db (really loud) to just 10 db (whisper). My gf thanks the CPAP machine for her quiet sleep. It's been a relationship saver.

Comment: While this does help those who regularly snore to the extreme, it does not answer the question for those who sometimes snore badly and often snore a bit (which seems to be most of humanity.)